# Intermittent "Memory exhausted" linker issue

Tags: c, compilation, linker, linker-errors

Facing `bin/ld: final link failed: Memory exhausted` linker issue intermittently while compiling 'C' code. I notice that there is enough memory available on build host while linking. But still hits into `Memory exhausted` issue.

I am using following liker flags. But no Luck :-

`-Wl,--no-keep-memory`

This issue occurs only with `debug` mode builds. Not for `release` builds.

Can any one give some data points to start debugging the issue?

Comment: You simply don't have enough memory on your system. If you're running in a virtual machine, try to add more memory for it. Otherwise add more swap to your system.

Comment: Another reason can be if your code contains a very long literal data, such as a large string or array, it can significantly increase memory usage during compilation and linking errors.

Comment: Do you have recursive includes or recursive defines?  Is this a big or small program?  If it is small (< 100 lines), could you post it?

Comment: "I notice that there is enough memory available on build host while linking." -- your linker tells you that you _don't_. You need to edit your answer and provide _evidence_ which led you to your mistaken conclusion.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I have verified that my build host has enough ram available.

Comment: How did you verify? And more importantly *when*? The need for too much memory could be very short and transient, not always possible to measure.

Comment: @CemPolat, How can we identify such very long literal data, large string or array? Its been huge code base. Any tools to identify such culprits ?

Comment: Since this is a linker error, there should be no compiler errors and all object files (.o) could be generated. So, check the size of the .o files. The corresponding .c /.cpp files would have huge static/global (and constant) initialized arrays. However, this assumption cannot catch static lib allocations. If there are huge explicitly initialized arrays you can initialize them with your code at startup. You can also write the data to binary files and read at startup.
One possible reason if you are using link time optimization in compiler that increases memory use. Try to remove  -flto.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , Just before running linker command i could view that ram is available i.e. 25GB..

Comment: @CemPolat, we are not passing -flto during linking. Also one thing to note is it is intermittent issue. Sometime build succeeds and sometimes build fails.

Comment: How complex is the program you try to build? How many libraries are used? How many object files? How large data do the program contain? Linking is *very* memory intensive, and if you have a large and complex set of files and libraries, with large amount of data in the object files, it might just not be enough. Especially since the linker isn't alone on the system, and it has to share the memory with other processes (which you have no control over).

Comment: Also, while there might be enough memory in general, fragmentation might mean there's no large enough contiguous blocks that can be mapped when needed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I am trying to create library linking lots of object files and static libraries. But i do have enough memory available on my build host. Just before executing linking step also i make sure to verify i have enough ram available.

Comment: Try monitoring the host memory *while* you're linking. If you use some kind of virtual machine or container, there are plenty of nice tools to help you with that. Same if you're using a CI system. It's not really enough to just get a snapshot before starting the build process.

Comment: could you please help with some tool for monitoring. I was just using free, meminfo for live memory usage.